# VSCode launch.json to debug node project within subfolder

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a node project as a subfolder within my main project. I am trying to create a launch config for VS Code so that it starts debugging index.ts file when I open the parent folder. Here's what my folder structure looks like:
[image: Folder structure]

So my node project is in the subfolder called NodeBackend. I want to press F5 or THE GREEN BUTTON on VS Code and start debugging my typescript file.

When I do that from within the parent folder I get an error:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

However, I can debug it without issues when I load the "NodeBackend" project in VS code and press F5 or THE GREEN BUTTON.

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\NodeBackend",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\NodeBackend\\src\\index.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my source code:
https://github.com/Kayes-Islam/SimpleProject

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: No unfortunately. I now have to open the subfolder that  has the package.json

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes for `cwd` and `program`?
Also, maybe this issue will help:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26726

Answer (score 1):

Here is my launch.json for a similar project structure:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Express",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend\\src\\app.ts",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "-r",
                "tsconfig-paths/register"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

The above configuration works though the console display the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register .\src\app.ts
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/path/to/project/backend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\path\to\project\backend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js.map'
(node:23068) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Hope that can help.
Cheers,

Comment: this project debugger launch configuration is working as per the requirement.